# Doctrine transaction using too much memory issue

Tags: php, orm, symfony1, doctrine

I keep on getting this error when running one of my scripts;

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size
>   of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 71 bytes) in ...
>   lib/symfony-1.4.11/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection/Statement.php
>   on line 246, ...

The following is the stripped-down version of the script that's
triggering the error;

```
public function executeImportFile(sfWebRequest $request)
{
 ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
 set_time_limit ( 0 );

 //more codes here...

 $files = scandir($workspace.'/'.$directory);

 foreach ($files as $file) {
   $path = $workspace.'/'.$directory.'/'.$file;

   if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
     $this->importfile($path);
   }
 }
}


protected function importfile($path){


 $connection =
sfContext::getInstance()->getDatabaseManager()->getDatabase('doctrine')->getDoctrineConnection();
 $connection->beginTransaction();
 try {

   //more codes here...


   while ($data = $reader->read()) //reads each line of a csv file
   {
     // send the line to another private function to be processed
     // and then write to database
     $this->writewave($data);
   }


   $connection->commit();

 } catch (Exception $e) {
   $connection->rollback();
 }
}
```

What the script does is basically to read all the csv files in a
folder (which contains tens of thousands of lines each), process it,
and the write it to the database using Doctrine's transaction.

While I don't think I need to set the memory limit and the time limit
in both functions, the script quits as Doctrine uses up all the the
allocated 1GB of memory.

It will normally stop after processing 10 files, and allocating more
memory will allow it to process a bit more files, and will still
crash.

Is there anything that I'm missing here that's causing the memory not
to free up after processing each files?

Mohd Shakir Zakaria
http://www.mohdshakir.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look to free any objects wherever you can, including query/connection objects, particularly when they're inside loops.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/improving-performance.html#free-objects

Comment: Thanks, I tried freeing the the objects and it solves my problem :)

Comment: Has anybody tried compiling Doctrine from within Symfony? any pointers to such a solution

Comment: @Prasad I'm coming late to the party, but I'll leave a reply for future reference. In Symfony "unset" won't work. You have to detach your the entities from the EntityManager via `$em->detach()` followed by `$em->clear()`, and then force PHP's garbage collector to work with `gc_enable();` and `gc_collect_cycles()` this is particularly useful when you're using doctrine within a loop. Just watch out with mapped and inversed relationships because using `$em->detach()` or `$em->clear()` too soon will cause cascading issues with your entities!

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine uses notoriously much memory when working with large datasets - importing large/multiple files is not possible this way.

Even though you import each file in their separate function call, doctrine has an internal object cache so they do not get freed.

Your best option would be to modify the task a bit, so it accepts a filename as parameter. If it's passed, process only that file (hoping it won't get too big). If no filename is passed, it loops through all the files like now, and calls itself via `exec`, so it's a different process and the memory really gets freed.

Comment: I am about to do something similar to the OP - I don't really see my need for Doctrine - am I going to run into problems using a PDO connection ?

Comment: Nope, PDO has no object cache like doctrine does.

Comment: Thanks ... So maybe thats an option for the OP ?

Comment: Depends - if he needs business logic contained in his models, definitely no. In general, different processes every few thousand records is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

the biggest issue I see in your script, is that your calling sfcontext really often. IMHO sfcontext is not a singleton, which means you create a new instance every loop. couldn't you pass the connection into the method?

```
public function executeImportFile(sfWebRequest $request)
{
 ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
 set_time_limit ( 0 );


$connection = sfContext::getInstance()->getDatabaseManager()->getDatabase('doctrine')->getDoctrineConnection();

 //more codes here...

 $files = scandir($workspace.'/'.$directory);

 foreach ($files as $file) {
   $path = $workspace.'/'.$directory.'/'.$file;

   if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
     $this->importfile($path, $connection);
   }
 }
}


protected function importfile($path, $connection){
 $connection->beginTransaction();
 try {

   while ($data = $reader->read()) //reads each line of a csv file
   {
     $this->writewave($data);
   }
  $connection->commit();

 } catch (Exception $e) {
   $connection->rollback();
 }
}
```

Comment: `sfContext` _is_ a singleton, see [sfContext source](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/util/sfContext.class.php)